# Why is my error message not showing in React Formik?

Tags: reactjs, formik, hilla, extract-error-message

I try to set an error message to a field, when submitting the form results in an error.
I use the useFormik. The Structure is like

```
InterfaceType : {
    names:[TranslationInterface]
}

TranslationInterface : {
    language: ENUM,
    value: ""
}
```

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {},
    onSubmit: async (value: InterfaceType, { setSubmitting, setFieldError,setErrors }) => {
        try {
            //api call which leads to an exception
        } catch (e: unknown) {
            console.log(e); // got here            
            const errors: FormikErrors<any> = {}            
            for (const error of e.validationErrorData) {
                if (typeof error.parameterName === "string" && getIn(formik.values,error.parameterName) !== undefined) { 
                    //path exists in formik.values
                    const key = error.parameterName;                    
                    setFieldError(key, error.message); // setting each field seems not to work
                    errors[key as keyof Ingredient] = error.message.substring(error.message.indexOf("validation error:"));
                }
            }
            setErrors(errors);            
            console.log(formik.errors); // still empty
            
        } finally {
            setSubmitting(false);
        }
    }
});
```

My field looks like

```
<TextField
    key={"field_" + translation.language + "_" + index}
    name={"names[" + index +"].value"}
    label={t("INGREDIENT_DETAIL_FIELD_NAME_" + translation.language)}
    readonly={viewModus=== ViewModus.OPEN}
    onChange={formik.handleChange}
    value={formik.values.names!.at(index)!.value!}
    errorMessage={getIn(formik.errors,"names[" + index +"].value")}>
</TextField>
```

The values got added to the formik.values correctly and the formik.handleChange also works. But the error message does not get displayed. The formik.errors seems to stay empty. Whether I use the setErrors or the setFieldError Method.

Comment: Your code looks very similar to mine here, which works, so I can't spot why it is not working in your case https://github.com/TatuLund/hilla-react-demo/blob/master/frontend/views/todo/TodoView.tsx

Comment: maybe its because of the nested object structure?